# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.IList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#, .net, generics

This is the error I encounter

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.IList<Model.DTO.RoleDTO>` to `System.Collections.Generic.List<Model.DTO.RoleDTO>`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

My code:

```
IList<RoleDTO> rl = new List<RoleDTO>();

        rl.Add(new RoleDTO{ roleId = new Guid("D3DCBCDA-AD61-4764-B5A1-057D654F1C26"), 
role = "admin" });


UserDTO user = new UserDTO 
             {
                username = "administrator",
                email = "administrator@email.com",
                role = rl
             };
```

And the model:

```
namespace Model.DTO
{
    public class UserDTO
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public IList<RoleDTO> role { get; set; }
    }

    public class RoleDTO
    {
        public Guid roleId { get; set; }
        public string role { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You declare `rl` as non-generic `IList`, while you try to assign it to a `IList<RoleDTO>` in `UserDTO.role`. Simply change the declaration of `IList rl` to `IList<RoleDTO>`.

Comment: I edited the typos, also I get this error : Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Model.DTO.RoleDTO>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Model.DTO.RoleDTO>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Every `List<T>` is an `IList<T>`, but not the other way around. Based on the edit, I assume `public IList<RoleDTO> role { get; set; }` actually is `public List<RoleDTO> role { get; set; }`. Read the errors carefully.

Comment: I don't get any errors with this code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just change `r1` to be `IList<RoleDTO>`.

```
IList<RoleDTO> rl = new List<RoleDTO>();
```

You cannot mix generic and non generic lists because `IList<T>` does not inherit from `IList` and `List<T>` does not inherit from `List` and does not implement `IList`.

**EDIT**

Based on the new error you have it means that somewhere you are trying to convert a `IList<RoleDTO>` to a `List<RoleDTO>` which can not be done implicitly because anyone could write a class that implements `IList<RoleDTO>`.  So you either need to do an explicit cast, or change the types to match.  The problem is that your current code does not show anywhere that a `IList<RoleDTO>` is being implicitly converted to a `List<RoleDTO>`.   But here's some guesses on my part.  If `UserDTO.roles` is actually defined as a `List<RoleDTO>` instead of `IList<RoleDTO>` then just change `r1` to be defined as a `List<RoleDTO>` or change `UserDTO.roles` to be a `IList<RoleDTO>`.  The latter would be my preference.  If you are assigning `UserDTO.roles` to a variable of type `List<RoleDTO>` you should change the type of that variable to `IList<RoleDTO>` instead.

Answer (score 4):

You are declaring rl as `IList`, not as `IList<RoleDTO>`

Change this:

```
IList rl = new IList<RoleDTO>();
```

for this:

```
IList<RoleDTO> rl = new List<RoleDTO>
```

Comment: @barrypicker Somehow SO was not showing my answer correctly, I just marked the relevant part as "code" and now it shows ok.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to update the

```
    rl.Add(new UserDTO { roleId = new Guid("D3DCBCDA-AD61-4764-B5A1-057D654F1C26"), role = "admin" });
```

with

```
    rl.Add(new RoleDTO{ roleId = new Guid("D3DCBCDA-AD61-4764-B5A1-057D654F1C26"), role = "admin" });
```

Comment: This was a typo, not the source of the error asked about in the question.